# Cannot get Log4net to work from Class Library

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I have a class library that performs a routine needed for installation.  From everything I have researched, I believe I have things set up correctly.  However, the routine absolutely will not log anything.  Here is what I have:

1. I have added the class library project as a reference to the host project.
2. In my class library, I have the following:

   ```
   private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
   ```

   ```
   public InstallDLL() {
     Log.Error("Where are you goinng?");
   }
   ```
3. In the host application, I have added the following line to the AssemblyInfo.cs class:  `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]`
4. Finally, this is the content of my app.config file:

   ```
   <configuration>

     <configSections>
       <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
     </configSections>

     <log4net>
       <appender name="TestAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
         <file value=".\Log Directory\MyTestAppender.log" />
         <encoding value="utf-8" />
         <appendToFile value="true" />
         <rollingStyle value="Date" />
         <rollingStyle value="Size" />
         <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
         <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
         <staticLogFileName value="true" />
         <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
           <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%M %C] - %message%newline" />
         </layout>
       </appender>
       <root>
         <level value="ALL" />
         <!-- If the following line is not included the log file will not be created even if log4net is configured with this file. -->
         <appender-ref ref="TestAppender" />
       </root>
     </log4net>
       <startup> 
           <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
       </startup>
   </configuration>
   ```

I have to be missing something, but what?  Keep in mind that logging works fine from the host application...

****  EDIT  ********************************************************************

I think I may know what is going on here.  The .dll file produced by this project runs BEFORE the host project runs because it is part of the installation script.  I think the host project has to run first to initialize the log4net configurations.  When I call the method in the .dll file FROM the host application, and not from the installer package, the log4net logging works just fine.  Does anyone know if this is root cause, and how I can get around this?

Comment: Not a duplicate.  I have already added the assembly reference to the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Comment: Add `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` in the entry point of your application. In `static void Main(string[] args)` method for example.

Comment: @Peska No affect.  :(

Comment: After your edit: Use the same `Configure` method, as I mention above. Move your log4net configuration to a separate file, something like `log4net.config`, and then use it like this: `XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));`

Comment: @Peska - Why do you think that would have any different effect on the issue?

Answer (score -2):

```
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />, Can you check your Target Framework in Assembly properties?
```

I just compared with my config file, I have this `<log4net debug="true">`. Could you please add this?

Comment: I just compared with my config file, I have this <log4net debug="true">. Could you please add this?